# Breaking a continuous contour shapefile into smaller parts?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, intersection, line

I created this contour shapefile and I need to break it into smaller parts so its better to manage. I also have a line shapefile of where I want the breaks. Is there a way to intersect and break them? I have tried everything I have available, maybe its something very simple that I'm missing. Thanks in advance!

I'm using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: yes, but the shapefile is coming out empty.

Comment: Did you try the [Clip](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000004000000) tool? (I meant clip earlier, instead of intersect - see above)

Comment: Yes, it isn't working either.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Split (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000006000000) to subset your data.

[image]

To illustrate, I added a new text field to the split features (i.e. 1-16 based on OID) and used that as the basis for the split.  There are 16 resulting shapefiles on the image to the right.

Also, try the [Split Layer by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808) script tool if you have licensing issues.  I believe you may need to intersect or union prior to the Split Layer by Attributes.

[image]

Comment: Best solution unless asker only has Basic license. Although just realised he/she seems to be wanting to use line features to clip with so will need to polygonize them.

Comment: I found this, but don't have the license for it.

Comment: @Naomy post edited to address your comments.

Comment: After figuring out wich attribute I needed to split them, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Union" in Analysis tools?

Comment: I tried, but its only for polygons.

Answer (score 0):

If a license higher than "Basic" is available a great option is the Planarize Lines tool on the Topology toolbar: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000008t000000.htm